# Alternative to Masonry horizontal or Flex direction CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking to a way to design my website a bit like this one that is inspirating to me : https://flink.to/

My research is more about the way the articles are showing up in a mosaic of squares of two different sizes.

I tried :

- Masonry horizontal (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonryhorizontal.html) but it doesn't really work in responsive as we can't assign a width and a height in percentage... I'm looking for a solution to display squares in that way.
- CSS with Flex direction, but It's not as powerful as it could be : if I have three rows of squares and a very-first-big square, more-little squares don't fill the empty space above the big one.

How could I replicate this in the best way ?

Comment: That page you have shown has all the additional tiles apart from the first one in the exact same size … so this could be accomplished with just very little CSS IMHO, no need for masonry or any advanced libraries at all …

Comment: It's an horizontal scrolling website and the tiles are firstly stacked from top to bottom, and secondly from left to right, which is complicating the way to do it. I tried with CSS columns but I couldn't manage to fit the height of the tiles to the height of the screen, as I want it responsive with percentage, and square forms (and by the way, the first tile is twice bigger than the others on the page I have shown).

Comment: Note that you can always view the source code of the web page, and browsers like firefox and chrome also let you see the html dom after javascript execution

Comment: Thank you, I know that and I'm already using the Chrome tool to do it. The problem is that my knowledge in Javascript is quite poor and I don't see any explicit JS plugin in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have found [Pure CSS](http://purecss.io/) and [CSS Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com) to be really simple and easy to use libraries for responsive grids in CSS.

[Here](http://purecss.io/layouts/gallery/) is an example of a similar layout using pure.css

In Pure CSS grids are laid out like this:

```
<div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-3"><p>Thirds</p></div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-3"><p>Thirds</p></div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-3"><p>Thirds</p></div>
</div>
```

And in CSS Skeleton like this:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="one-third column">1/3</div>
    <div class="two-thirds column">2/3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="one-half column">1/2</div>
    <div class="one-half column">1/2</div>
  </div>

</div>
```